# Nil Can't be coerced into Fixnum in map

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a line that does a total of all labor.  However if the value is nil it throws a:

```
nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

Is there a way to determine if the value is nil before it hits the "Fixnum"? I have tried a couple of different places in the code but it keeps throwing errors.

```
<div><span>Total Labor: </span><%= @labors.map{|item| item.total_labor}.reduce(0, :+) %></div>
```

Be gentle I'm still a noob..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `compact` to remove nil values from your array, and then sum all of them:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact

```
@labors.compact.map{|item| item.total_labor}.reduce(0, :+)
```

Or, as @ajedi32 said:

```
    @labors.map{|item| item.total_labor}.compact.reduce(0, :+)
```

Comment: You may want to move the call to `compact` after the call to `map`, just in case one of the items has a nil `total_labor` attribute.